# Bash auto-delete script

Tags: bash, script, shell-script

I'm looking for a bash script that would auto-delete oldest folders (lets say last 3) in a directory when the available space drops below X gigs.

I've read related posts but since I don't know anything, I don't know how to safely modify the scripts myself.

Comment: Include the links to the related posts. I will try to modify them for you. Just be very specific about which directories you want to work on.

Comment: Just want to note that finding the "oldest folder" can be tricky.  If you create /foo/bar/baz.txt, then bar's modification time will be updated, but foo's will not.  Likewise, if you *modify* /foo/bar/baz.txt in place, not even bar's time will be updated because no directory entries were changed.  If this needs to be taken into account, let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tailor the PARTITION, DIR_TO_CHECK, LIMIT and NUM_DIRS_TO_DELETE, BLOCKSIZE and NUM_DIRS_TO_DELETE to suit you needs.

The LIMIT is the number of gigabytes available.

BE CAREFUL WITH THIS, once you uncomment the rm command, the directories it deletes are gone!

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'

PARTITION="/dev/sdb1"
DIR_TO_CHECK="/home/bryan/temp/*/"
BLOCKSIZE=1000000000 
LIMIT=12
NUM_DIRS_TO_DELETE=4


if [ $(df  -B $BLOCKSIZE  $PARTITION | tail -1 |  awk  '{ print $4}') -gt $LIMIT ]; then
  echo "plenty of space"
else 
   for i in $(ls -d $DIR_TO_CHECK --group-directories-first  -tr | head -$NUM_DIRS_TO_DELETE)
   do

      du -h $i
      # When you are happy that the script does what you want, 
      # delete the above line and remove the # character from the below
      # rm -r $i 
   done
fi
```

Comment: There are two ways this script will fail. The biggest is that you can't rely on `-f18` being the correct field number because the number of spaces will vary depending on the length of the number strings. It would be better to use AWK to pick the field. Also, if there are spaces in filenames or directory names, the `for` loop will fail. `ls -d /foo/*/` will only list directories because of the final slash. `df -k` lists sizes based on 1K blocks, but it's unclear whether your `LIMIT` variable is in bytes or K-bytes. You should use `$()` for command substitution instead of backticks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, have made the changes. Please take another look at it and let me know what you think.

Comment: A silly question: will the script check constantly for the if condition or only on execution? And if only on execution, how to make it execute in some time intervals or on new folder creation?

Comment: It will only execute when called. If you want it to run a regular intervals use cron - http://clickmojo.com/code/cron-tutorial.html.

Comment: I tested the script and it works great except one thing - it checks the available space on the drive (sda3 in my case) but Id like it to check the space available to my home dir.  Theres about 150 gig of space on the drive where /home is mounted but only 60 gigs are assigned to me. And sorry to be so picky :>

Comment: Tried using du ~/ -s instead of df but then the -gt wont work.

Comment: Ok, just figured it out - used du with awk print $1 :)